# is there a point to "optimize" types on iOS devices?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arm

Here I was just writing some code that dealt with an integer value of -24/+24, and I made my method return an int...  And I thought to myself-- should I really be using a short in this case?  I know it might have mattered back in the day when memory for something was 48k-- but in today's modern world does it really matter?

Is it ok to just be "int happy", even when I know my numbers are going to be very small?

Comment: This is kind of subjective, but yes, I think it's okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All ARM CPUs have 32-bit integer registers and at least a 32-bit wide L1 bus, so using a `short` will give absolutely no advantage [1], and may in some cases be detrimental to performance.

Leave the variable as an `int` and be safe in the knowledge that you'll get an optimum register width pretty much wherever you run the code.

[1] The exception to this rule being when using the NEON unit - in which case a 16-bit operation offers more parallelism than a 32-bit operation.

Comment: This having beaten my essentially identical answer to the punch, all I'd add is that if you want to expand the question out beyond return types then it's a question of scale; if you have 10,000,000 records that you want to get into memory then cutting two bytes from each would obviously make a significant difference in iOS's memory constrained environment. But 99% of the time it's not worth worrying about.